# SQL Intersect or Left Join with subquery? Disputes/Corrections table

Tags: sql, join, intersect

My SQL is shamefully rusty. I was thinking this is case for INTERSECT, but I want to make sure.

I have two tables.[image]

Table 1 has a whole bunch of rows that are coming in from a feed. We have no control over them and any corrections to their values will be undone when the feed sends new data. Some of the data isn't correct though, hence Table2 acts as a Disputes or Corrections table. If the Attribue1, Attribute2, Attribute3 fields of a particular row in Table1 are incorrect, a row is created in Table2 with the "correct" values for those fields. I can link the two tables by a foreign key (MatchKey1 in my picture).

I basically want to get the all rows from Table1 but with Table2 corrections when they exist, as if it was all one table with the "correct" information to begin with. Since Table2 does not get wiped out, the corrections will remain when the feed updates Table1 so long as a link can be made between two tables.

Example:

**Table 1**

*Row 1: {1, 00A1, Yellow, Fish, Happy}

Row 2: {2, 00A2, Red, Cow, Sad}*

**Table 2**

*Row 1: {00A1, Green,  Cat, Happy}*

**The query would produce:**

*{1, 00A1, Green, Cat, Happy}

{2, 00A2, Red, Cow, Sad}*

Row 2 in Table 1 remains, as does the "Happy" (Attribute3) value in Row1, but the Attribute1 and Attribute2 values show the "corrected" values.

If not INTERSECT, would a some sort of Left Join (possibly with subquery) be better?

Select * Table1 Left Join Table2 on Table1.Matchkey1 = Table2.MatchKey1

I want to exclude the "incorrect" field values from the columns of the same name in Table1 though.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this situation with a simple `COALESCE` statement and a `LEFT JOIN` (example in oracle or db2):

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryKeyID
     , Table1.MatchKey1
     , COALESCE(Table2.Attribute1, Table1.Attribute1) AS Attribute1
     -- and so on
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN
Table2
ON Table2.MatchKey1=Table1.MatchKey1
```

If `COALESCE` isn't available in your dialect, use `CASE WHEN ... IS NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END` instead. Note that this query assumes that each field in `Table2` is filled when the JOIN was successful -- otherwise, you can have mixtures of the attributes of both tables (e.g., `Attribute1` and `Attribute2` of `Table2` and `Attribute3` of `Table1`) -- this might as well be desired.